# How do I Create a Dynamic ImageView side by side with a ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout, imageview

[This is the effect I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caGeO.png)

The number of circles depends on the number of children in the ListView and I cant seem to achieve the same effect by using the background as a line and a circle ImageView for each child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe in your Adapter, there is a getCounts() functions that is publicly exposed. You can use the `getCounts()` function to get the number of children in your ListView.

---

I think its better if you actually just place the `imageView` as a part of the item that will be a part of your list view. This way you don't have to worry about the number of items and then making that many circles. That's highly inefficient too.

Comment: How would I use that to get an image view side by side the list view? Wouldn't I have to wait until I populate the list view to get count?

Comment: I see what you mean. On second thought, it would be unwise because if you have 50 items, you are going to be inflating 50 images. You should instead put the circle as a part of the layout of the list view. This way for each item, you already have the matching circle inside of that list item.

Comment: I've tried that but I'm unsure of how to get the line behind the circles and not interfere with the listview

Comment: Have you tried drawing the lines to fill the height of the list view? That way it may look like separate items, but they are still connected?

Comment: I haven't tried that, thanks for the suggestions! I'll test it out